# python beautifulsoup search across multiple lines

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to search for the P/E ratio of a finance page, from the input code shown below. So, essentially I am trying to extract '48.98' from the source.
As the structure is same for Market cap, book value, etc. I am unable to frame the correct code for a soup.find

Would be very grateful for the correct structure of the soup.find code. 
I am a newbie and sorry if i am asking something very basic..
Thanks in advance !

```
<div class="FL" style="width:210px; padding-right:10px">
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">MARKET CAP (Rs Cr)</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">41,364.28</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">P/E</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">**48.98**</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">BOOK VALUE (Rs)</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">147.24</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">DIV (%)</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">1000.00%</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">Market Lot</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">1</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
<div class="PA7 brdb">
<div class="FL gL_10 UC">INDUSTRY P/E</div>
<div class="FR gD_12">60.95</div>
<div class="CL"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the text to find the  div with *"P/E"* and get the next div:

```
price = soup.find("div", class_="FL gL_10 UC", text="P/E").find_next("div").text
```

If it is always the second div with the css class *FR gD_12*, you could also just get the first two and extract the second

```
price = soup.select("div.FR.gD_12", limit=2)[1].text
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic!  This was a big help.